# Is it possible to have Jekyll automatically render code blocks raw?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to have a Jekyll site hosted on Github, and it will have a lot of code blocks that have code similar to Liquid templates. Which is problematic because Jekyll tries to render it, even though whatever variable or function doesn't exist

I know it's possible to escape using `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}`, but is there a way to make Jekyll just always compile code raw? I don't think I'll ever need to actually use Jekyll's functionality in a code block, and I'd rather stick to normal markdown syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> but is there a way to make Jekyll just always compile code raw?

Not really ([I don't see any configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) to enable raw by defaultà, considering Jekyll has to interpret other Liquid templates outside of the code block.

As seen in [jekyll issue 5549](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5549#issuecomment-258523935), `{% raw %}` remains the official solution.

Answer (score 0):

re: way to make Jekyll just always compile code raw

Not that I have found, but if the code is contained in a separate file I created an include tag to automatically wrap the contents in `{% raw %}` / `{% endraw %}` instructions (which prevents the need to manually edit the file):

https://github.com/klandergren/jekyll-include-raw